# Rails Devise No Method Error for Registrations for Stripe Checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a registration form for paying for an event using `stripe`. But I'm getting an error when I submit the form.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
NoMethodError in Users::RegistrationsController#create
undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #7):

def create
  super do |resource|
    if params[:objective]
      resource.objective_id = params[:objective]
      if resource.objective_id == 1
```

Here's my controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
# whitelist the following form fields so that we can process them
protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) { |r| r.permit(:stripe_card_token, :password, :password_confirmation, :email, :first_name, :last_name, :company, :street, :city, :state, :zip, :phone, :roadshowcity, :comments) }
  end
end
```

My Registrations Controller (**where I'm currently getting the error**):

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # Extend default devise gem behavior so that users
  # signing up with the registration form (roadshow)
  # save with a special stripe subscription function.
  # Otherwise Devise signs up user as usual.
    def create
      super do |resource|      **<====Error here(NoMethodError undefined method `to_sym' for nilclass)**
        if params[:objective]
          resource.objective_id = params[:objective]
        if resource.objective_id == 1
          resource.save_with_registration
        else
          resource.save
        end        
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :regis

  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token, :id
  # If user passes validations (email, pass, etc.),
  # Call stripe and tell stripe to set up a subscription
  def save_with_registration
    if valid?
      @product_price = Objective.find(objective_id)
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(email: email, card: stripe_card_token, description: stripe_card_token.to_s)

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer => customer.id,
        :amount => 900,
        :currency => "usd",
        :description => "Registration"
      )
      self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
      save!  <----- Error here(no method!)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The error ended up being cause by the `model` code:
`self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id`
Which should have been:
`self.stripe_customer_token = charge.customer`
Changing this fixed the issue.